# On next execution, CTR proceeds from previously failed step

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I have the composed task `myFailedTask` with 2 steps and one of them is configured to fail all the time :
`<mf1: sampleTask --fail=true --custom-argument=m || sampleTask>`
On first run, the job runs with `run.id` equals **1** and and `mf1` is reported as failed.
Next time I run the CTR,the job is run  with `run.id` equals to **1** again and   `sampleTask`  step is skipped:

```
2017-11-29 15:30:30.146 INFO 11604 --- [ taskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler : Step already complete or not restartable, so no action to execute: StepExecution: id=97, version=3, name=myFailedTask-sampleTask_0, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=1, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=
```

I'm executing the CTR using the `httpclient` transformer deployed with below properties file :

```
app.httpclient.body-expression='name='+new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readTree(payload).findValue('taskName').asText()+ \
'&arguments=\
--increment-instance-enabled=true \
--split-thread-core-pool-size=10 \
--interval-time-between-checks=5000 \
--composed-task-arguments=--message='+new String(T(java.util.Base64).getEncoder().encode(payload.getBytes())) 
app.httpclient.http-method=POST
app.httpclient.url=http://localhost:9393/tasks/executions
app.httpclient.headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

I also change the `--composed-task-arguments` via different payload between CTR invocations -  same effect.

So, my question is how could I force the CTR to run new job and not proceed the previously failed job from the failed step.

**UPDATE**

OK, digging into spring sources, the below code from `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner::getNextJobParameters` explains  the behavior:

```
if (isStoppedOrFailed(previousExecution) && job.isRestartable()) {
                // Retry a failed or stopped execution
                parameters = previousExecution.getJobParameters();
                // Non-identifying additional parameters can be removed to a retry
                removeNonIdentifying(additionals);
            }
            else if (incrementer != null) {
                // New instance so increment the parameters if we can
                parameters = incrementer.getNext(previousExecution.getJobParameters());
            }
```

So I'm rephrasing the original question : "How can I pass the `restartable` attribute to CTR ?

Comment: How are you launching the CTR?

Comment: Via stream : `http | httpclient | log`,  I've also specified the  `httpclient` deployment properties  in the question

Comment: @michael-minella, the post body looks like this : `{
"taskName":"myFailedTask"
}`

Comment: We will åddress it in https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/issues/23.